# Why InertiaJS SSR takes long time to load the app?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I'm working on a Laravel, Jetstream InertiaJS with SSR support and VueJS project locally. Whenever I refresh the page it takes a while to show me the content of the page. I'm worried that this might happen in production as well.

The project is really empty, it's a brand new project and I haven't done anything yet.

[image: Long loading time gif]

I used chrome performance recorder to see what is taking time the most and here is the outcome:

[image: Debug for issue]

Any other Laravel project that I have works super fast except any project that I install with InertiaJS SSR. Has anyone tried it in production?

Comment: Could be a lot of things, can you provide more information about how you run things locally? Which language/software versions? The node process for SSR might use an above average amount of memory on your PC, how much memory do you have available?

Comment: I'm working on a windows 10 computer with 8GB of RAM. @JohnZwarthoed